# Cracks up wall in corner of room

Tags: walls, foundation, cracks

We recently did a comprehensive remodel of our very old condominium.  Its a four unit row house from the 1890's.  I noticed that there is a long crack going up the corner of a back room.  Is this a common thing when a new coat of compound and paint is applied?  Or is the building settling because of the cold weather, or is there a major structural issue?  I'm noticing a similar thing with the grout in the floor / wall corner of the bathroom. Kind of cracking an separating a bit.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the crack is occurring where the new remodeled walls meet the older existing walls, it’s due to shrinkage in the new lumber.

New lumber has moisture in it that will slowly evaporate causing the stud to shrink. It may shrink only a 1/64” or so, but that’s enough for the new gypsum board to pull away from the existing wall.

You can fix this by removing the stud (only the stud adjacent to the existing wall needs to be replaced) and install a “dry” stud (a stud rated “KD”...kiln dry) which is very expensive or wait about 1 year until most of the shrinking has occurred. Then patch and paint the crack.